# Architecture of Website based on java

Tags: java, applet, daemon, java-web-start

I've just started programming with Java, so might appear as silly question, but I was not able to find simple answer on the internet. This is "big" question which I have to answer before getting too deep into development, so you can help me to save a lot of time on trying different approaches.

I am currently creating a website using Java. Important feature of this website would be realized through separate Java thread (like daemon) which must be run in background for as long as the user is on the website. At the sametime, website applets must have means of communication with this thread.

I see three potential solutions to this:

1. Create traditional multipage website with stand-alone java applets in each separate page. I am not sure if it is possible, the following questions arise:

   - is it possible for java thread created by java applet to continue execution after user navigated to another webpage (on the same website)? I assume that yes.
   - is it possible for newly launched java applet to communicate with java thread already running in background? (I've seen part of documentation covering communication between java applets through JavaScript, not sure that this can be used in my case. Any other options?)
2. Create single-page website, with one single java applet, responsible for all navigation and rendering all pages. This solves the problem with background daemon, which becomes easy to implement and communicate with, as part of single applet, but raises one more questions:

   - I know that applet can modify current webpage. Is it feasible to use this feature to simulate navigation between different pages?
3. Create Java Webstart application, basically by taking the single java applet from p.2 and converting it into stand alone application.

I want the whole thing to have a look and feel of website, so I would prefer option 3 over option 2 and option 1 over option 2.

Thank you for any thoughts you share.

UPDATE:
Does anybody know answers specifically to the two questions under p1? If it is possible to work with java threads the way described?

Now I would most probably opt for making a Java Webstart Application. This should be the least painful way.

UPDATE 2:
I finally decided to work on single java applet, which can be easily converted to JWS application if needed. Nature of my project is that I need to make impression of working with website, that's why I am putting additional efforts to make it appear as a website. For knowledgeable people it will be obvious, that it is more like a local application.
Solution I chose has following benefits in my situation:
- easily convertable from JWS application to Java applet and back.
- no problems with running background thread and communicating with it.
- more reliable security (meaning that I don't need to use any mechanisms to pass over session ids from one applet to the other)

Contras:
- if size gets large, start up will be slow - I hope to avoid this.
- Security issues - I tried signing the applet and it helped a lot.
- Work of navigation buttons in browser (back and forth) - I hope to be able to replicated it in applet. Think applet should be able to catch this event.

Comment: why do you want to use applets at all in this case?

Comment: @naresh  That is a very good question!  I eagerly await Stanislav's answer.

Comment: Why I want to use applets:
It should not be only applets, it can be anything, but there is one important thing which I should have probably mentioned in the post: the logic, architecture and the whole idea of this "website-application" relies on significant amount of data processing at the client. I can't move this processing to the server without killing the whole idea.

Comment: After reading first bunch of comments my thinking started "shifting" to p.3 - Java Webstart Application. Or p.2, like JWS in the browser.

Comment: If you are prepared to put all the logic into a rich client app. then a free floating JWS app. might make sense, but *"I want the whole thing to have a look and feel of website,.."*  a free floating app. is furthest from that, amongst the options outlined!

Comment: I've updated my answer to include information that addresses your 2 bullet points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Java thread [...] which must be run in background for as long as the user is on the website

If the thread being forked is to preserve state while the client is logged in then I would use a database, memory cache, or some other persistance layer to hold the client session state.  This is a much more typical model.  You can also have multiple frontends that share session information across the network.

If you are not talking to a browser then creating a stand-alone web application may be the best choice.  You can still use HTTP as your transfer protocol in which case I'd recommend using a Java web implementation like [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/).  This would involve significantly less technology and complexity.

If you need to implement web pages, I would certainly use proper frontend models and technology.  You should separate your pages into multiple applets -- or multiple controllers/views in the MVC model.  Using the applets should be fine.  They (or the controllers) should call a centralized service which starts, communicates with, and stops the background threads depending on the information flow.

I would also certainly have another background thread running to time out your client threads in case a client never returns.  Your worker threads could just exit after a certain amount of waiting.

Hope this helps.

---

> is it possible for java thread created by java applet to continue execution after user navigated to another webpage (on the same website)? I assume that yes.

Yes.  Threads that are forked will continue to run until they terminate or (if daemon) the process terminates.

> is it possible for newly launched java applet to communicate with java thread already running in background?

Sure.  What they need is some mechanism to be able to share data.  For example, your background thread service could keep a `Map` of the thread objects with the key being some sort of client-id.  Whenever a thread wanted to talk to it's background thread then it could call the service to lookup the thread by id.  Something like:

```
BackgroundStream thread = threadService.getThread(clientId);
thread.callMethod(...);
```

If there was some sort of synchronous question/response then you'd need to have a condition variable or something.  Read up on [Java threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Gray, best answer so far.
My thread is not only to preserve connection, it is going to do some work, connection to server once in a while, so I can't easily substitute it with database / persistance layer. (if I correctly understand what you mean). It must be thread running some specific background loop.

More specifically - do you know if it is possible to have background thread shared by all applets on the website?

I will take a look at Jetty, thank you very much!

Comment: Sure.  One thread could service all of the applets as long as your get the inner-thread communications correctly.  Devils in the details there but the Java threads documentation should help with this.

Answer (score 0):

There's an architecture used in Website applications in Java, it's called a [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Frameworks such as Java Server Faces (Standard on Java EE 5 and higher), Struts (1.x or 2.x), Spring, Apache Wicket, etc. were designed to create web applications using MVC model. The question is, would you prefer the component-based architecture of the framework (such as JSF) or not (which you shouldn't be worried about at this moment)

Applets is defnitely a bad choice as applets are downloaded to client side. Some browsers don't support Applets especially in mobile web browsers and its difficult to apply security settings to untrusted applets, plus you may not know if the client has blocked the applet or not.

Comment: *"(and it must be avoided at all cost)"*  That is just silly. *"it has restrictions such as client-server networking."*  Only sand-boxed applets, and even then, only foreign sites.  While I doubt that the solution to the OP's actual (as yet unstated) goal will involve applets in any way, that last paragraph is so wrong as to deserve a down-vote.  Care to edit, to spare me the trouble?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I know that applets can have some security concerns and I will have to use client-server networking, so will definitely run into it. I will be using signed applets with JNLP, so this should help, at least in some way. Due to reasons I explained in comment to my post above, I can't move processing to server.

Comment: *"..when a new Applet update is available, the browser will download the full applet"* Not with the new abilities provided via JNLP (lazy downloads, programmatic control of downloads..).  *"you may not know if the client has blocked the applet or not."*  There are ways to find out.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, I know there are ways to find out, but its the client decision whether to unblock it or not.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - I am not trying to "sneak into" somebody's PCs, so it's perfectly fine if client needs to approve applet before working with it.

Comment: *"its the client decision whether to unblock it or not."* Of course it is, as it should be.  *"I know there are ways to find out,"* So why state *"you may not know"* - that is ***not*** the same thing as an applet being blocked and you knowing about it.

Answer (score -1):

Applets are a bad choice because of 2 reasons:

1) First, they are executed on client's browser and not on server. Therefore you cannot perform any backend processing(Business logic or fetching data from server database) using applets.

2) Applets are very buggy and have security issues. That's why applets are out of fashion these days.

Now coming to how you can create website using java technology, for that you need to start understand Java Server Side programming. Start learning about Java Servlets and Java Server Pages. To put it in simple terms, they are java programs which are executed on a web-server or application server.

then start reading about Java Enterprise Edition.

refer this [tutorial for Java Enterprise Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not being specific enough in initial post - idea I am trying to implement can't be done using Server side programming. It relies significantly on data processing at client. I know I must have mentioned this, specifically because nowadays everybody is so much into "cloud-computing" :)

Comment: Well, you could either:
* switch to JavaScript for the processing (you might not be so happy with this however) ;
* use GWT to compile Java to JavaScript.
You will not be able to use threads in GWT.

Comment: For client side processing, you can any client side scripting language like  javasript or a javascript library like JQuqery or flash(it has its own problems) :)

Comment: *"So if you cannot perform any backend processing(Business logic or fetching data from server database) using applets."*  With the word 'if' that seems like a question.  Without the 'if', it is just plain wrong.  Edit or suffer a down-vote.

Comment: sorry @andrew I didnt notice that, that was a typo.i will edit my answer.

Comment: Well, you edited out the 'questionable question' and it is now 'just plain wrong'.  I have not entered a down-vote ..yet.

Comment: Could you please share some knowledge in what is wrong with "First, they are executed on client's browser and not on server. Therefore you cannot perform any backend processing(Business logic or fetching data from server database) using applets", please share with us if back-end server processing can be done using applets?